# Can't download images using a bitmap

Tags: c#, bitmap

My code:

```css
var imagePath = Path.Combine(Config.FtpFolder, filePath);
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; MDDC)");
wc.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/x-shockwave-flash, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*");
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
Stream s = new MemoryStream(wc.DownloadData(url));
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(s);
bmp.Save(imagePath);
bmp.Dispose();
wc.Dispose();
```

Data:

```
url = "https://vnn-imgs-a1.vgcloud.vn/photo-2-baomoi.zadn.vn/w700_r1/2019_06_01_287_30932992/eb8b020b0f4be615bf5a.jpg"
imagepath = C:\image1\2019/06/03\anhdaidien-5(2).jpg
```

When running, I get an error

> ERR Parameter is not valid.   at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Stream stream)

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Drawing_Bitmap__ctor_System_IO_Stream_) suggests you can do what you are doing, so perhaps there is something wrong with the image you are trying to download or maybe the stream contains HTTP headers?

This is the code from the documentation, which is slightly different to yours, but should work:

```
try
{
    System.Net.WebRequest request = 
        System.Net.WebRequest.Create(
        "http://www.microsoft.com//h/en-us/r/ms_masthead_ltr.gif");
    System.Net.WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    System.IO.Stream responseStream = 
        response.GetResponseStream();
    Bitmap bitmap2 = new Bitmap(responseStream);
    PictureBox1.Image = bitmap2;

}
catch(System.Net.WebException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("There was an error opening the image file."
       + "Check the URL");
}
```

Comment: My code works with every previous image url but not this url (DATA)